# Assume that T is a linear transformation. Find the standard matrix of T.

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand $\mathbf{e}_2 + 24\mathbf{e}_1$, but I do not understand $x_2 = -x_1$. What is $x_2$ and $-x_1$ referring to? This is the part that is preventing me from doing these types of questions.

> Assume that $T$ is a linear transformation. Find the standard matrix of $T$.
>
> $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, first performs a horizontal shear that transforms $\mathbf{e}_2$ into $\mathbf{e}_2+24\mathbf{e}_1$ (leaving $\mathbf{e}_1$ unchanged) and then reflects points through the line $x_2=-x_1$.
>
> ---
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{e}_1 & \mathbf{e}_2+24\mathbf{e}_1
> \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 24 \\ 0 &  1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
> $$ The reflection through the line $x_2=-x_1$ maps $\mathbf{e}_1$ into $-\mathbf{e}_2$. Notice that this reflection is a linear transformation.
>
> This means $\mathbf{e}_1$ maps into $-\mathbf{e}_2$ and $\mathbf{e}_2+24\mathbf{e}_1$ maps into $-\mathbf{e}_1-24\mathbf{e}_2$.
>
> Write the column vectors for the transformation $\mathbf{e}_1=-\mathbf{e}_2$ and $\mathbf{e}_2=-\mathbf{e}_1-24\mathbf{e}_2$.
>   Please explain what this part means, why, and how to solve the problem. Also, please include a diagram of if possible.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are the components of a vector $\mathbf{x}$ with respect to the standard basis. This means that:
$$
\mathbf{x}=[x_1,x_2]^T=x_1\mathbf{e_1}+x_2\mathbf{e_2}
$$

(Maybe that you prefer the notation $x_1 =x$ and $x_2=y$ so that the vector is $\mathbf{x}=[x,y]^T$, but it is the same).

So the line $x_2=-x_1$( or $y=-x$) is the bisector of the second and fourth quadrant and the reflection through this line is represented  by the matrix:
$$
T_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as you can easily see reflecting $\mathbf{e_1}$ and $\mathbf{e_2}$.

So your transformation is $T=T_2T_1$ with
$$
T_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1&24\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we have:
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\-1&0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1&24\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\-1&-24
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand your entire answer, but why did you choose to multiply in the order T_2T_1? How does one know which order to multiply in?

Comment: Your question says: '' **first** perform a horizontal shear...and **than** reflects point through the line ...''. This means that when we apply the transformation to a vector $\mathbf{x}$ the order is: $T(\mathbf{x})=T_2(T_1(\mathbf{x}))=T_2T_1\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your help! :)